# How to sort result based on the entry in other table

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I've 2 tables in my schema

Table A

```
+----+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | abc  | NULL | abc  |
|  2 | abc  | NULL | NULL |
|  3 | NULL | abc  | abc  |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Table B

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
| NULL | abc  | abc  |
| abc  | NULL | abc  |
| abc  | abc  | abc  |
+------+------+------+
```

I want to select all the records in the Table A and sort them if it has same entry in the Table 2.

In this case my answer would be

```
+----+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | abc  | NULL | abc  |
|  3 | NULL | abc  | abc  |
|  2 | abc  | NULL | NULL |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Any help or notion would be appreciated

Comment: What happens if Table B has more than one record?

Comment: Whatever rows that matches with the table2 has to be at the top of the resultant answer.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question, so I guess I'll ask again.  What happens if Table B has more than one record?

Comment: Modified my example with your case. Please have a look at it

Comment: This is bad table/database design IMO.  You would need to cross join the tables and even this leaves other questions remaining.

Comment: Actually my schema deals with seller stock and buyer requirements. I want to display all the requirements to the seller and the requirements matching with the seller stocks has to be put at the top. Now how do I modify the database or query?

Comment: How do you want to deal with the situation that a record in a has several records in b which match equally well?

Comment: Well in that case put the record to the top of the result. The logic is if it matches any of the records in the table b that goes to top. Doesn't matter where it comes in the order but it should be above in order such that the records which didn't match should be at the bottom.

Comment: Actually, here are my thoughts on the design problem.  I think it might work better if you put the attributes into separate _records_, rather than separate columns.  For one thing, what if your stocks end up having dozens of attributes?  This could quickly become a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I think I have an answer give me 5 min

Comment: Actually the product has 7 attributes and the requirements has the exactly same attributes just values varies between each product. I tried out your first solution with cross join and I made the id of the table a as DISTINCT. I worked well with multiple rows in the table b.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.col1,        a.col2,        a.col3 FROM tab a CROSS JOIN tab1 b ORDER BY        (CASE WHEN a.col1 = b.col1 OR (a.col1 IS NULL AND b.col1 IS NULL)              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +        (CASE WHEN a.col2 = b.col2 OR (a.col2 IS NULL AND b.col2 IS NULL)              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +        (CASE WHEN a.col3 = b.col3 OR (a.col3 IS NULL AND b.col3 IS NULL)              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC; This worked well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT id, col1, col2, col3
FROM (
   SELECT id, col1, col2, col3, matches,
          @seq := IF(@id = id, @seq + 1,
                     IF(@id := id, 1, 1)) AS seq
   FROM (
      SELECT t1.id, t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3,
             IF(t2.col1 IS NULL, 0, 1) + IF(t2.col2 IS NULL, 0, 1) + 
             IF(t2.col3 IS NULL, 0, 1) AS matches
      FROM tableA AS t1
      LEFT JOIN tableB AS t2 
         ON COALESCE(t1.col1,0) = COALESCE(t2.col1,0) OR 
            COALESCE(t1.col2,0) = COALESCE(t2.col2,0) OR 
            COALESCE(t1.col3,0) = COALESCE(t2.col3,0) ) AS t
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq := 0, @id :=0) AS vars         
   ORDER BY id, matches DESC  ) AS x
WHERE x.seq = 1 
ORDER BY x.matches DESC, x.id
```

The query uses a `LEFT JOIN` operation with `OR` operators in the `ON` clause, so as to get all possible matches of each record of `tableA` with each record of `tableB`. Variables are used in order to get the best matching record of `tableA` per `id`. The result is ordered by the number of matches of each `tableA` record.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01354/1)

**Note:** The query assumes that `col1`, `col2`, `col3` never take the value `0`.

Comment: Can I also have the no of rows matched with the table b for each row in table A as new column in the answer? so that the rows that did not match with the table b will have the count as 0?

Comment: @SamuelRobert Yes, my query uses `matches` field for this. Just add it in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Although one small change the left join in the inner query logical operator should be AND instead of OR